# Gradle WriteProperties: property inside doLast did not work

Tags: gradle

Gradle WriteProperties: property inside doLast did not work.

```
 task foo(type: WriteProperties) {

    doLast {

        def value = getValueFromFile()
        property 'foo', value
    }
 }
```

The property foo inside the doLast was ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review [build script basics](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html). `doLast { }` is executed at the **end** of a task's action list. In other words, the main task's action is executed first and then any `doLast` actions.

What you have done is configured the property `foo` **after** the task has executed. Since no properties were configured to be written prior, the `foo` task is a essentially a [noop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) because none of the inputs are configured.

Additionally, you have not declared the file as an input to the task. This will lead poor [incremental builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/incremental_build.html) support.

Complete example:

```
tasks.register("foo", WriteProperties::class) {
    outputFile = layout.buildDirectory.file("foo.properties").get().asFile
    val examplePropertiesFile = layout.projectDirectory.file("example.properties")

    // Declare the file as input to the task to allow Gradle to track
    inputs.file(examplePropertiesFile)

    // Lazily compute/read the value
    val examplePropsValue = provider {
        val props = Properties()
        examplePropertiesFile.asFile.inputStream().use {
            props.load(it)
        }
        props["foo"]
    }

    // Configure the property for the task
    property("foo", examplePropsValue)
}
```